# Laravel 8.75 multiple authentication Routing issue

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-8, php-7.4

I am working on laravel 8.75 with php 7.4.9.
I am facing issue in laravel route getting error too many redirects.
[image: Error Image]
I want to create route http:127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login
by firing command php artisan route:list i am getting routes like this[image: Route List Image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you  are using the same url (admin/login) in get method and post method of login page

- So try to change the url to one of them and try again after run `php artisan route:clear`